# Htaccess URL rewrite domain with wildcard

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm using htaccess to manage friendly urls

My friendly URL looks like this:
www.example.com/p/12345/John-Smith

12345 is the ID number, /p/ doesn't change, and the name is irrelevant bit of friendly url. My background url looks like this:
www.example.com/page.php?id=12345

My htaccess looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^p/([0-9]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ details.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Everything works like a charm.

However, what I really want my htaccess to look like is below.  The only different is the ^(.*)/p/ versus just ^p.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/p/([0-9]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Basically, I want to ensure that only a directory of /p/ in the url triggers this particular htaccess rule and not something unintended, like example.com/gdp/12345/abc

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why this isn't working!

Thanks in advance as always.

Comment: The first rule rewrites yoururl.tld/p/1234/Name and the second rule rewrites like this: yoururl.tld/Something/p/1234/Name but not yoururl.tld/Somethingp/1234/Name .. so this is exactly what you described. Tell me if I got you wrong?

Comment: `^` mean the start of the url. So nothing is allowed in front of `p/...`. So `example.com/gdp/12345/abc` will never match the first rule. Just try it out. You rule already does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)/p/([0-9]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ page.php?id=$1 [L]` has some issues.

1. You're not backreferencing the correct id: The first ( ) matches what is before the `/p/` so $1 will backreference that, and not the id.
2. URI's passed through rewrite rules when they are in and .htaccess file have the leading / stripped off, so the regex `^(.*)/p/` will *never* match something like http://www.example.com/p/1234 because the URI that is being passed into the rule is `p/1234`.
3. The other weird thing in your rules is you redirect everything to http://www.example.com/ which seems like it would be a redirect loop, but if that works for you then that's fine.

To deal with 1 and 2 you need to change your backreference to **$2** and your regex to accomodate a `p/1234` URI:

```
RewriteRule (^|/)p/([0-9]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ page.php?id=$2 [L]
```

The `(^|/)` says that either it's the beginning of the URI (for `p/1234`) or it's a slash (for `/something/p/1234`).

Comment: Thanks Jon.  You're right, it was a non-start because I forgot to change the $1 to $2.  Still that didn't fix it until the (^|/)/ was edited, which I would've never figured out.  Thanks very much!